# Capybara and select tag reloading another select tag using ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm with a problem here. There are two select on view and there is an `onchange` on the first. When the user changes the first select, the second is reloaded via ajax. It is working as well.

My problem is write that in capybara.

```
select all('#unit_id option').last.text, from: 'unit_id'
select all('#places_options option').last.text, from: 'places_options'
```

Unit reloads Place, but it is not happening on specs. I had already created the unit and place for created unit. The first command is working perfectly, but the ajax is not running and therefore places is empty.

Comment: are you using `js: true`? also which driver?

Comment: When i try with js: true, the spec does not find the another elements. I had tried with capybara-webkit and selenium-webdriver, but it is not working :/